# Edit PDF text from an exported AI

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe-illustrator

I need to edit some PDF documents dynamically, I am trying to do that with iTextSharp.
These PDF documents are in fact .AI (Illustrator) files renamed to PDF. Inside the file are named objects which names are important for me to use.
I would like to loop all objects inside the pdf and use some logic related to the name and alter the text inside this object.
So, is this possible?
I am guessing that the PDF objects aren't complex enough to have names and such, but thats just a guess.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, used Illustrator DLL to edit the variables and then exported it to PDF using doc.SaveAs('filepath', class_pdfoptions);
then with pdfsharp.net created an empty pdf document, opened several pdf I exported with Illustrator and merged them into this new doc, saved and sent to the printer.